# Building qcow2 Images using packer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kvm, packer

As part of our CI/CD process, we are building qcow2 images to start KVM based VMs on bare metal machines.
We are building them using [packer](https://www.packer.io/) which, in the process, starts a KVM based VM.

Now we are thinking about moving the CI/CD Process (not the production environments) to AWS.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to start KVM VMs in AWS (except when using extremely expensive bare metal instances).

Are there other ways to build qcow2 images in AWS using a packer? Or some other technology?